# Status strip vs notify Icon

Tags: c#, user-interface

As part of a program, there are situations in which the user has to be quickly notified that something is going on. 
I was thinking of using Notify Icons. For some reason, they appear but don't dissapear automatically as I expected. (As in toasts in other platforms)

Then I found the status strip. Which seems convenient too and simpler to program although I have to manually remove the message

or should I go for the old MessageBox as I have been doing so far.

what are the pros or cons on using those methods of communication with the user?

Comment: So, you criticize with Notify Icons, that they don't disappear automatically. But status strip and messageboxes don't do that either. For a messagebox you even need user interaction.

Comment: it was not a criticism. Just what is happening to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your usecase and the importance of your message to the user you'll have to consider the following points:

- Is the message important enough to stop the users current workflow immediately, like a messagebox does?
- Is it okay, if the users misses a message, because it disappears automatically after a certain amount of time?

A messagebox is clearly the most intruding way of communicating with the user. The status strip on the other hand can easily be missed. Notification Icons including a balloon tooltip are somewhere inbetween. The ballon will most certainly close after a few seconds. But you could also add a timer to remove the notification icon itself after a certain amount of time, too.